# Creating term fails in SP 2013

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am trying to create a term in a SP 2013 term set. I am able to read the terms from the term set with the given credentials.

Settings:

The ServiceAccountLogonName user is one of the Term Store Admins

Code:

```
var siteUrl = ConfigHelper.GetValue("SharepointSiteUrl");

var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigHelper.GetValue("ServiceAccountLogonName"), ConfigHelper.GetValue("ServiceAccountPassword"));

var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);

var termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores.GetById(new Guid("dae0745c07ae40d6bf4b6c52e3172d6a"));

var termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(new Guid("f40eeb54-7c87-409d-96c7-75ceed6bff60"));

foreach (var tagName in tagNames)
{
    var newTerm = termSet.CreateTerm(tagName, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID, Guid.NewGuid());
    newTerm.CreateLabel(tagName, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID, true);
    termStore.CommitAll();
    clientContext.Load(newTerm);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Error message when ExecuteQuery is run:

Failed to read from or write to database. Refresh and try again. If the problem 
persists, please contact the administrator.

Does the credential need any specific rights on the term store or term set?

Is there anything else I am missing here?

Useful tutorial:
https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/blob/master/O3656/O3656-8%20Developing%20advanced%20Taxonomy%20Scenarios%20in%20Office%20365/Lab.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your user has permissions to term store.
Go to central administration ==> manage service application ==> click on line (not link) of your service application ==> choose "Permissions" ribbon button and add your account.

Also make sure that your term set ist open for term creation. You can check the "IsOpenForTermCreation" of you termSet variable.

Third. Use Guid.NewGuid() instead of new Guid() in CreateTerm line.

Had time for some tests:

```
        foreach (var tagName in tagNames)
        {
            var newTerm = termSet.CreateTerm(tagName, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.LCID, Guid.NewGuid());
        }

        termStore.CommitAll();
        clientContext.Load(termStore);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This worked for me after I've added my user to service application permissions.

Comment: I do not have access to the central admin. I will have to request the SP admin to look into that. I will keep you posted once the permissions are updated.

Comment: IsOpenForTermCreation returned true and I am using Guid.NewGuid() but I got the same error.